# Uri.AbsolutePath C# WPF содержит странный путь

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

До недавнего времени все было хорошо и тут, код, который я не менял, начал делать что-то невменяемое, а именно - выкидывать вот такой вот абсолютный путь из Uri на локальном компьютере:

[image: Скриншот, показывающий полный путь к файлу]

Коды, нужные чтобы разобраться (а может и нет):

Метод, в котором генерируется исключение:

```
    public static string GetSongsName(string mp3filePath)
    {            
        //Строка которая выкидывает ошибку (что логично, судя по absolutepath из передаваемого Uri):
        Mp3File mp3tags = new Mp3File(mp3filePath);
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(mp3filePath);

        string[] tags = new string[2];
        if (mp3tags.HasTags)
        {
            tags[0] = mp3tags.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag).Title;
            tags[1] = mp3tags.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag).Artists;                
        }
        if (tags[0] != null && tags[1] != null && !tags[0].Equals("") && !tags[1].Equals(""))
        {
            return tags[0] + " - " + tags[1];
        }
        else
        {
            if (!HelpsMethod.GetTitle(mp3filePath).Equals(""))
            {
                return tags[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return file.Name.Remove(file.Name.Length - 4, 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Класс, который содержит поле типа Uri

```
    public class Song
{
    private static int Counter = 0;

    #region Fields
    private string _artist;
    private string _title;
    private string _absolutePath;
    private int _duration;
    private int _number;
    private bool _isLocal;

    //Мой вопрос касается этого поля:
    private Uri _songUri;
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    public string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return _artist;
        }
        set
        {
            _artist = value;
        }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
        }
    }
    public string AbsolutePath
    {
        get
        {
            return _absolutePath;
        }
        set
        {
            _absolutePath = value;
        }
    }
    public int Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return _duration;
        }
        set
        {
            _duration = value;
        }
    }
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
        }
    }
    public bool IsLocal
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLocal;
        }
        set
        {
            _isLocal = value;
        }
    }

    //Мой вопрос касается этого поля:
    public Uri SongUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _songUri;
        }
        set
        {
            _songUri = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public Song(string Title, bool IsLocal, Uri SongUri, string Artist = null, int Duration = 0)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Duration = Duration;
        this.IsLocal = IsLocal;
        this.Artist = Artist;

        //Мой вопрос касается этого поля:
        this.SongUri = SongUri;
        Number = ++Counter;
    }                
}
```

Метод, который вызывает метод, который вызывает исключение:

```
        private void addToPlaylist()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openMusic = new OpenFileDialog();
        try
        {
            openMusic.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|MP3 Music (*.mp3)|*.mp3";
            openMusic.FilterIndex = 2;
            openMusic.Multiselect = true;
            openMusic.Title = "Select a music file";
            if (openMusic.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                foreach (string item in openMusic.FileNames)
                {
                    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item);

                    Mp3File mp3tags = new Mp3File(item);
                    string[] tags = new string[2];
                    if (mp3tags.HasTags)
                    {
                        tags[0] = mp3tags.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag).Title;
                        tags[1] = mp3tags.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag).Artists;
                    }
                    if (tags[0] != null && tags[1] != null && !tags[0].Equals("") && !tags[1].Equals(""))
                    {
                        ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist.Add(
                            new Song(tags[0], true,
                            new Uri(item)
                            , tags[1]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!HelpsMethod.GetTitle(item).Equals(""))
                        {
                            ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist.Add(
                                new Song(HelpsMethod.GetTitle(f.Name).
                                Remove(HelpsMethod.GetTitle(f.Name).Length - 4, 4),
                                true,
                                new Uri(item), HelpsMethod.GetArtist(f.Name)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist.Add(
                                new Song("", true,
                                new Uri(item), f.Name.Remove(f.Name.Length - 4, 4)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ModelMainWindow._MediaPlayer.Open(ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist[ModelMainWindow.Index].SongUri);


            //Вот здесь смотрим содержимое абсолютного пути из нашего Uri
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist[ModelMainWindow.Index].SongUri.AbsolutePath);

            //Вот тут кроется ошибка (при вызове метода "GetSongsName" после передачи ему абсолютного пути
            //из Uri
            ModelMainWindow.SongName =
                Helpers.HelpsMethod.GetSongsName
                    (ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist[ModelMainWindow.Index].SongUri.AbsolutePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Повторюсь, ничего из этого кода небыло изменено, просто внезапно Uri при использовании AbsolutePath вместо строки в виде "D:\file\file.file" стал выдавать то, что на скриншоте.
Буду очень признателен, если кто-то подскажет в чем может быть проблема.

UPD. Спустя ночь, так я и не понял, что могло случиться с Uri.AbsolutePath. Сделал по другому, но менее приятно =\

Кто знает, дайте ответ, что не так с Uri при работе с локальными файлами, жутко интересно.

Comment: На скриншоте Uri явно содержит русские буквы. При исключении вам надо декодировать Uri